# DAX not adding values

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have the following DAX formula

The following expression doesnt seem to add value a and b. It just shows value A instead.

What am I doing wrong?

=IF(Table[cost]="Fees of consultants";
Table[a]+Table[b]; 0)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the formula?

Remember, data source (column formulas) work at the row level.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculated-columns-in-power-pivot-HA102836183.aspx

Measures can work at the table level.  The example below from technet does a condition SUM at the measure level.

```
=CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[SalesAmount]), DimChannel[ChannelName]="Store")
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272049.aspx

Is this a row calculation or a table calculation?